Priority of overflow: auto in a div hierarchy
I am struggling with CSS with what is probably a pretty simple problem: I have a hierarchy of , all using flex / flex-column, that are displayed in a fixed size container (an iframe).
Deep in the hierarchy there is a "description" div that contains a potentially long textual description; I gave it a min height of 4em.
Assuming we start from an iframe high enough to accomodate everything without scrolling, as the frame's height is reduced I'd like to

first reduce the description (and make it scrollable( down to 4em,
then once that's not enough make the top-level container scrollable

This codepen CSS fiddle demonstrates the issue:
CSS fiddle
The main issue is that if I set overflow-y: auto on the parent then it becomes scrollable without trying to constrain the description down to its min height first.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks!
HTML (Pug):
div(class="main") 
   div(class="parent")
      div(class="form")
         h4 Title
         div(class="description") Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

         button(class="button") Click me

CSS:
.main {
   width: 24em;
   height: 16em;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   background-color: lightgreen;
}

.parent {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

h4 {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   row-gap: 1em;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

.description {
   flex: 1 1;
   // height: 0;
   min-height: 4em;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

.button {
}


In CSS there is no way to specify which overflows are handled first. Solving this requires Javascript. And by the way, your codepen does not render anything.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What shorter code would you suggest? I fixed the codepen - apparently the site lets you share a link which won't actually work unless you are logged in - sorry.

A new CSS fiddle that shows a working solution for a hierarchy of flex & grid containers: https://codepen.io/Franck-Mangin/pen/LEPyMox

You're almost there, no JS required, just do some minor changes. see and run the code:


.main {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 24em;
  height: 18em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;

  /* for the demo purpose */
  animation: breathe 8s 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.description {
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.button {}

/* for the demo purpose */
@keyframes breathe {
  to {
    height: 4em
  }
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="form">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <div class="description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div>
      <button class="button">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Works like a charm, thanks! Not sure how I missed giving giving the form a height.
